# CakePHP Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp, inflector

Let's start with a simplified version my code:

**Model**: Sku.php

```
class Sku extends AppModel {

}
```

**Controller**: SkusController.php

```
class SkusController extends AppController {

    public function admin_add() {

        $this->layout = 'admin';

        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Sku->save($this->request->data)) {
                // Do stuff
            }
            else // Do stuff
        }

    }

}
```

**View**: Skus > admin_add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Sku', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Sku.item_no')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Sku.size'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Sku.color'); ?>
<button type="submit">Save SKU</button>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

When I submit the form I get the error **Call to a member function save() on a non-object**. At the beginning of my controller file if I add the following everything works fine and a new row is inserted into the skus table.

```
public $uses = 'Sku';
```

If I have used all the proper naming conventions shouldn't I be able to omit the previous line? Furthermore, If I change all of the file and class names to Test following the same naming conventions it works without the $uses variable. This leads me to believe I have some sort of conflict elsewhere in my code. Any suggestions as to why this may be happening or where to look for a potential problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don' follow the naming convention. Check http://inflector.cakephp.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Looks like the inflector cant turn the plural to singular: http://dogmatic69.com/inflector/Skus. So either you have to go with $uses or you add the rule to the inflector. [See the inflector configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration).

You're not using an array or boolean for the Controller::$uses property.

```
public $uses = 'Sku';
```

Should be:

```
public $uses = array('Sku');
```

Actually you don't have to define it at all if the the controller and model match the conventions.

Read the documention http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Controller.html#$uses

> `$uses` An array containing the class names of models this controller
>   uses.
>
> Example: `public $uses = array('Product', 'Post', 'Comment');`
>
> Can be set to several values to express different options:
>
> - true Use the default inflected model name.
> - array() Use only models defined in the parent class.
> - false Use no models at all, do not merge with parent class either.
> - array('Post', 'Comment') Use only the Post and Comment models. Models Will also be merged with the parent class.
>
> The default value is true.

Comment: $uses does not need to be an array unless the controller uses multiple models. Also, I stated that I am using the proper conventions so why should I even need to include $uses. Your answer was already covered in the question.

Comment: Looks like the inflector cant turn the plural to singular: http://dogmatic69.com/inflector/Skus

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, I think, it'll work

**Model**: Sku.php

```
class Sku extends AppModel {
  var $name = 'Sku';
}
```